# Iterate using model output and multiple distinct (grouped) inputs

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-modeler, iteration

In QGIS 3.26 I have the following model (ERASE target layer from base layer), and I'm trying to iterate over the model so that the output layer is automatically entered as the input layer into the second/third/etc. iteration of the model (visualization included). The trouble is that I want to specify a new buffer distance and new target layer in the following iterations.

If possible, I'd like to create a group of layers in the Layer Panel and select this group as the desired target layers (and enter the buffers manually or load a text file that contains the buffer distances).

I'm a python novice, but I'm open to running the process as a script.

[image: Model diagram]
[image: Model interface]
[image: visualization of desired model/script]